# Tool for helping decide where new datacenter components should be placed?

Tags: monitoring, floor-plan

I am looking for a software tool helping me to find an **optimized** place where new datacenter components, such as servers and network devices, should be placed.

Important criteria are:

- climate of room and of rack
- output of rack
- power consumption of new device
- rack units
- SAN-Ports free/needed
- LAN-Ports free/needed

There are tools for doing listings to find out which component is where placed (common DCIM tools). But how to find the optimized place for new devices. Which tool (plugin, module) could help ?

Answer (score 1):

DC planning software is pretty common so by all means [shop around](http://www.google.com/search?q=datacenter+planning+software).  The product I've seen most recently is  [Emerson Power planner](http://www.emersonnetworkpower.com/en-US/Products/InfrastructureManagement/DataCenterPlanningandManagement/Pages/AvocentDataCenterPlanner.aspx).
A former employers colo provider used it to monitor pretty much everything.

IIRC it requires sensors to be placed throughout the datacenter so you can only use certain features if you own the datacenter, but it's pretty robust.  It allows you to track several different data points all from one pane of glass.

Comment: I am knowing the tools your mentioned. But I am looking for a tool calculating for me the optimal place (rack and slot position) for a new server.

Comment: What would you consider the optimal place for a new server?  I'm not sure that much thought goes into placement of servers in a rack.  Cooling should be the same for the entire rack so the only thing left is cable management and the weight of the server.  Doesn't seem like something I would write software for.  Maybe I'm missing something though.

Comment: Gave my comment before reading carefully the pages you provided. You are right, the tool you mentioned is not only for doing inventory but also for planning.